# How to resolve xcode 10.1 unable to launch app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode10.1

[unable to launch app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL1aj.jpg)

My app runs on Iphone simulators and when I run my app on my actual Iphone7, installation seems to work.

However, running on Xcode while the phone is connected causes the error in this picture.

Also, the installed app on my phone does not run at all.

Can anyone help me get out of this?

Much thanks in advance :)

Comment: for some reason, the xcode doesn't even bother to pop up the error screen now. It says the app finished running app on my phone when it did not run anything. Only the white screen briefly pops up on my phone. Can any xcode master help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your iPhone and Xcode must either

1. be updated to the latest firmware.

or

2. match each-other in versions.

To clarify 2, if an iPhone is on iOS 12.1, Xcode should be on version 9.1. The number after the decimal matters the most. Your app won't work if your iPhone is on iOS 12.1 and Xcode is on 9.0!!

Last but not least, trust the installed app by following these steps:

Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management -> Company name -> Trust

This way your app will run for sure on your iOS device! Peace!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the app is trusted the Author in you device which you want to run :

Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management -> Company name -> Trust the app if not done yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done that and xcode still won't run any of my apps now :( Is this maybe because I have exceeded the number of apps allowed to create in 7days?

Comment: after shift+command+k and running again, my app ran on my iphone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it took me long time to see what happens. If you have created new provisioning profiles, be sure that Xcode is using the right one.

Go to General -> Signing -> Click on the Team -> Add an account.

Then...

[Click on Manage Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sV4t.png)

[Click on "+"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPMW8.png)

[Select the one you need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLp4v.png)

If this doesn't work, reboot the mac and the phone.